# Updating input in each row with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a table showing a list of 'sightings' in my case and each specific column can be updated as the value are displayed in  field, etc. Each individual row has an update button on it where I would like to click when I have finished updating that particular row. This is my forEach loop displaying all the entries:

```
<c:forEach var="mySightings" items="${mySightings}">    
            <tr>
                <td><input name="id" class="data sighting_id" disabled value="${mySightings.id}"/></td>
                <td><input name="total_pests" type="number" value="${mySightings.total_pests}"/></td>
                <td><input name="date" type="date" value="${mySightings.date}"/></td>
                <td><input name="username" disabled value="${mySightings.username}"/></td>
                <td><textarea name="information">${mySightings.information}</textarea></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="update_sighting btn btn-success">Update</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="delete_sighting btn btn-danger" value="${mySightings.id}">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>       
</c:forEach>
```

This is my Ajax function, which I think is definitely wrong:

```
$(".update_sighting").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateSighting",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $("#alert").show();
            alert("Submitted");
            $(".errormsg").hide();
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        } 
    });
});
```

Do I need to change something to my ajax code? I dont know what I should do next?
And my Controller which handles the request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateSighting", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updateUser(Sighting sighting, Model model) {
    sightingsService.updateSighting(sighting);
    List<Sighting> sightings =  sightingsService.getAllSightings();
    model.addAttribute("sightings", sightings);
    return "allSightings"; 
}
```

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with serialising the data. You are calling it on the `button` element instead of a `form`, but even then that would serialise the entire form, not just the row which was clicked on. So you need to build the object to serialise manually:

```
$(".update_sighting").click(function(){
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateSighting",
        data: {
            id: $('input[name="id"]', $row).val(),
            total_pests: $('input[name="total_pests"]', $row).val(),
            date: $('input[name="date"]', $row).val(),
            username: $('input[name="username"]', $row).val(),
            information: $('input[name="information"]', $row).val()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#alert").show();
            alert("Submitted");
            $(".errormsg").hide();
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: I just tried to implement this. It still has not managed to update. I do get an alert message saying "Submitted", but when I refresh the page the updated content is not there.

Comment: What do you mean by `update content`? Your success handler is showing/hiding a couple of div elements, it does not do anything with the `response` coming back.

Comment: What I mean is when I go to another page, then return back to this page  to view all the listings. The row I changed previously prior to returning to this page has not got the changes.

Comment: Have you checked your server-side code is updating the database correctly?

Comment: Ok so I got it working now. It does update, but leaves the fields blank after I click update? Any ideas?

Comment: Check the network traffic in Firebug to see what information is actually being sent in the request.